# What does it mean for a java member variable to be GC-free

Tags: java

I stumbled upon a comment like the following in apache tomcat source code in org.apache.coyote.Request.java:

```
    This is a low-level, efficient representation of a server request. Most
 * fields are GC-free, expensive operations are delayed until the  user code
 * needs the information.
```

What could GC-free mean? How do you make the JVM not run garbage collection on a variable and wouldn't that be dangerous?

Comment: Are the fields primitives by any chance?

Comment: It's not about not running the GC, it's about not generating garbage. For an object to be GC free it must not generate any garbage - it must not dereference objects; must never allow anything to become eligble for GC.

Comment: @BoristheSpider gotcha. That's a sensible explanation, though the choice of term the author used could have been more explanatory. Thanks

Comment: @christopher and to answer your question, no, they are not all primitives. However, if nothing is ever derefenced, Boris's explanation still holds.

Comment: *" ... the choice of term the author used could have been more explanatory"* - 1) We are talking about source code comments here ... not javadocs.  2) The kind of programmers who are the intended audience (i.e. other maintainers) would know what he meant.  3) If you think the comments should be improved, submit patches!

Comment: @BoristheSpider care to offer an answer. question doesn't feel like it deserves to be closed.

Comment: @StephenC  That's incorrect.  The specific comment mentioned is in the [Javadoc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/coyote/Request.html).

Comment: I stand corrected.  However, my two other points remain correct.

Answer (score 3):

Link to [org.apache.coyote.Request.java](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/c4b006e3dd46ca8604b2c9418a4714b6261aab7c/java/org/apache/coyote/Request.java) on Github.

They are not saying that they made the JVM not run garbage collection.  What they are saying is that the fields do not generate garbage that the JVM needs to collect.  A better term might be garbage-free rather than GC-free.  Or recyclable memory.  In fact, if you look at [org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.java](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/c4b006e3dd46ca8604b2c9418a4714b6261aab7c/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/buf/MessageBytes.java), they use the term recyclable.

You can read more discussion of this at [Java Development without GC](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/java-development-without-gc/).  Warning, they are trying to sell you a commercial product to examine your memory usage and look for garbage leaks.

The basic concept is that if you allocate memory, you store it in an allocation pool.  Instead of allowing it to go out of scope and be garbage collected, you keep it in scope and reuse it at the next allocation.

In **Request.java**, you may want to check out the `recycle` method.  That seems to be what clears the old memory and prepares the object for reuse.